# Шифрование и дешифрование методом Виженера на СИ

Tags: c

Вот код шифрования, все прекрасно шифруется, проблема с изменением с расшифровкой.

Я меняю формулу

```
c=(s+k[i])%32
```

на

```
c=(32+s-k[i])%32
```

32 прибавляю, чтобы не получалось отрицательных значений. В результате он записывает какой-то бред, либо символы непонятные, либо просто буквы, то есть не расшифровывает, в чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    printf("Please, input key: ");
    char k[255]; // ключ 
    scanf("%s", k);
    FILE *f= NULL, *q= NULL;



    f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if(f==NULL) {
        printf("Error 1");
        return 1;
    }

    q= fopen("crypt.txt", "w");
    if(q==NULL){
        printf("Error 2");
        return 2;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int c; // код символа шифра
    char s; // символ из файла для шифрования

        fscanf(f,"%c", &s);
    while(!feof(f)){// пока не конец файла
        if(s!=' '){

            c=(s+k[i])%32; 
            if (c >255) {           
                c=c%255;
                while(c<224){
                    c=c+32;     
                }
            }
            fprintf(q, "%c",c);
            if((i+1)!=strlen(k)){
                i++;
            }else i=0;
        }else fprintf(q, " ");
        fscanf(f,"%c", &s);
    }

    fclose(f);
    fclose(q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что у вас int c; я бы поставил для c и s типы unsigned char, выкинул бы "логику" работы с отрицательными числами и смотрел в отладчике что там не так.

Comment: типы как только не менял, все равно не получается расшифровать

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, впервые прошу помощь на форуме. Проблема в том, что не получается расшифровать текст  и я не могу решить эту проблему, так как  совсем мало знаю язык си

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в следующем: формула зашифровки, которую вы привели, исходит из того, что коды букв лежат в промежутке 0..31. Преобразование `x -> (x + c)% 32` циклически переставляет символы в этом промежутке. Для ASCII-символов (или, хуже того, символов UTF-8) предположение не выполняется, они занимают любую позицию в промежутке 0..255.

У вас при шифровании получается не более 32 различных значений для каждого символа. Понятно, что результат теряется. Таким образом, уже операция шифрования необратимо портит текст.

Попробуйте заменить константу 32 на 256 (как для шифрования, так и для дешифрования).

Да, и попробуйте разобраться в назначении остатка кода. Игры наподобие `if (c >255) c=c%255;` совершенно неудовлетворительны. Плохое знание языка — не извинение, код принадлежит **вам**, и вы **обязаны** понимать его.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то код, наверное, какой-то такой получается:

```
  int kl = strlen(key), c, i = 0;

  while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
    int s = key[i++ % kl];
    fputc((decrypt ? (c - s) : (c + s))  % 256, out);
  }
```

Comment: Не совсем, надо `(256 + c - s)`, т. к. например `-1 % 256 == -1` (а `fputc` принимает `int`).

Comment: [Хотя](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fputc.html): converted to an **unsigned char**. Так что должно работать.

Comment: @VladD, да должно оно работать, поскольку fputc младший байт выводит.

Comment: Не сработало бы для любого _другого_ модуля, кроме 256. Но тогда по сути и `% 256` не обязательно.

Comment: И ещё, я бы обратил все байты ключа до цикла. Хотя преждевременная оптимизация, чтение из файла всё равно медленнее.

Comment: @VladD, точно, `% 256` не нужно. А по поводу обращения ключа до цикла -- я вообще не понял. Мы же просто циклически берем его байты в цикле.

Comment: Я имел в виду, пройтись по ключу и сменить знак у всех байт один раз до главного цикла (для случая декодирования), тогда тернарный оператор внутри главного цикла станет не нужен больше.

Comment: @VladD, ага. Это хорошее решение. Только надо не забыть скопировать перед этим константу (если используется ключ по умолчанию, а не всегда он читается из файла или argv[]) в массив перед модификацией ключа.

Comment: Точно! Символы скорее всего read-only, если не пришли от пользователя.